# Compare and hash out unwanted entries in text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having below 2 text files with service details in them

**File_1**

```
Application Host Helper Service,OS,WARNING
Astro BLSA (Business Logic Server Authentication),OS,CRITICAL
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Cb Defense,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
Astrogyprocazwatch,OS,WARNING
Astroweberazwatch,OS,WARNING
```

**File_2 (Service List which are having startup type as automatic)**

```
Application Host Helper Service                                  
Astro BLSA (Business Logic Server Authentication)                                                     
Base Filtering Engine                                            
Background Tasks Infrastructure Service
Cb Defense,OS,WARNING
```

I want to compare **File_2** with **File_1**. If the entry in **File_2** present in **File_1** the ignore else put a **#** in front of the line to comment that.
and if it is already commented then it should not get commented again.

The changes should reflect in **File_1** itself

**Expected Output**

```
Application Host Helper Service,OS,WARNING
Astro BLSA (Business Logic Server Authentication),OS,CRITICAL
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Cb Defense,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
#Astrogyprocazwatch,OS,WARNING
#Astroweberazwatch,OS,WARNING
```

Only last 2 entries in **File_1** is not present in **File_2**, so they got commented and rest which are already present/commented will remain as it is.

I was trying the below code, but it is putting **#** for all the entries and double **#** for already hashed entries

```
$File_1 = gc "\\$svr\c$\\Services_20062023.txt"
$GetAutomaticServices = Get-Service | where {$_.StartType -eq "Automatic"} | select DisplayName | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | out-file "\\$svr\c$\\Automatic_service_list.txt" 
$File_3 = gc "\\$svr\c$\Automatic_service_list.txt" 

foreach($entries in $File_1)
{
    $Final_arr += ($entries -split ',')[-3]
}

$file_2 = $Final_arr | ForEach-Object {
    if ($File_3 -match "$_")
    { "$_" }
    else { "#$_" }
}
```

Above updated code is working fine but only problem is which are already commented, this code is adding another **#** in front of it.

Please let me know how do this

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO isn't a code writing service - no-one is going to take the time to do your job for you, but if you show some effort in solving it yourself, you'll likely get help with specific issues.

Comment: @boxdog: I forgot to add the tried code. my mistake

Comment: `match` will match *any part* of the input strings(s). You probably want to do: `$File_3 -match "^$_$"` or better: `$File_3 -Contains $_`. As an aside: You didn't initialize the `$Final_arr` array (`$Final_arr = @()`) besides it is better to [avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026)

Comment: So in your code `$File_3` is what you call `File_2` in the explanation above? In which case the content of `Automatic_service_list.txt` will not match your listing for `File_2` ...

Comment: @Thor: `So in your code $File_3 is what you call File_2` -Yes.
If values present in `Automatic_service_list.txt` not available in `$File_1`, we have to comment that entry in `File_1`

Comment: @iRon: I tried using your suggestion. `-contain` is commenting all the values. and `match`  condition I am currently using is working fine. only problem is I am not able to ignore the lines which are already commented. so the code is adding extra `#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pitfall in your question as it contains a lot of [trailing spaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/utility-modules/psscriptanalyzer/rules/avoidtrailingwhitespace) in `$File2`.
Anyways (using the PowerShell [*when the input is a collection, the operator returns the elements of the collection that match the right-hand value of the expression. If there are no matches in the collection, comparison operators return an empty array*](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#common-features) feature):

```
$File1 = @'
Application Host Helper Service,OS,WARNING
Astro BLSA (Business Logic Server Authentication),OS,CRITICAL
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Cb Defense,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
Astrogyprocazwatch,OS,WARNING
Astroweberazwatch,OS,WARNING
'@ -Split '\r?\n'

$File2 = @'
Application Host Helper Service
Astro BLSA (Business Logic Server Authentication)
Base Filtering Engine
Background Tasks Infrastructure Service
Cb Defense,OS,WARNING
'@ -Split '\r?\n'

$Split2 = $File2.Foreach{ $_.Trim().Split(',', 2)[0] }
$File1 | Foreach-Object {
    if( $_[0] -ne '#' -and -not ($Split2 -eq $_.Trim().Split(',', 2)[0])) {
        "#$_"
    } else {
        $_
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting the service lines inside the `ForEach` loop, this will make printing the lines much easier.

Now for matching `DisplayLine` reliably in a multi-line fashion, I think you need to use regular expressions and match the line with anchors (`^` and `$`) to `$File_3` with `sls` (`Select-String`).

```
$File_1 = gc services.txt;
$File_3 = gc automatic-services.txt;

$File_1 | % {
  $pattern = [RegEx]::Escape(($_ -split ',')[0]);
  if ( ($_ -match '^#') -or ($File_3 | sls "(?m)^$pattern$") ) { $_ }
  else { "#$_" }
}
```

Note the `(?m)` in the regular expression makes the anchors match on line-breaks, see the [regular expression quick referense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#regular-expression-options) for more details.

Output:

```
Application Host Helper Service,OS,WARNING
Astro BLSA (Business Logic Server Authentication),OS,CRITICAL
#Base Filtering Engine,OS,WARNING
#Background Tasks Infrastructure Service,OS,WARNING
Cb Defense,OS,WARNING
#Cb Defense WSC,OS,WARNING
#Astrogyprocazwatch,OS,WARNING
#Astroweberazwatch,OS,WARNING
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but when I tried the code, all the entries are getting hashed out

Comment: @snehasishnandy: which version of powershell are you running this in? Check the output of `$PSVersionTable`